# Track another Tab in the same browser

Tags: javascript, php, browser

I am building a time tracking application for my organisation.
I have a website ready and launched with the AUX and Breaks to punch, let's name it AUXY. Now I need to take data from another website(In different tab of same browser) let's name it LAYS. If one goes active/away on the LAYS, how can I detect that.

Currently I'm scraping Dashboard of LAYS which takes up a lot of time as all the employee's details are fetched and there is a delay of 1 min 30 sec. I need to make it real-time.

Is there a way to track the active/away activity of LAYS from AUXY, as they will be open in the same Browser? AUXY is developed using PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: Are there two different domains for AUXY and LAYS?.. Do you have an access to the LAYS's code?

Comment: Yes, AUXY and LAYS are on different domains.
I do not have access to LAYS Code, but I have the access of LAYS Dashboard and permission to scrape it.